# SSIS package fails when run by SQL Agent - "Invalid character value for cast specification"

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS package which reads data from .xml and .xlsx files and writes them to staging SQL Server database. The package is deployed to SSIS catalog on Microsoft SQL Server (Enterprise) instance. When the package is executed by SQL Agent job step it fails with the following error message:

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005
>
> An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft OLD DB Provider for SQL Server" Hresult: 0x80004005. Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification".

When the same package is run manually from Visual Studio it works just expected. There is no problem with feeding data to staging tables.

Any idea what can caused this issue?

Comment: Are you running against the same file in VS and within the agent? A Google implies that *somewhere* you're likely trying to convert an empty string, or `NULL` character to a different datatype (like a date).

Comment: They are same files. The error message suggests the problem with data type (conversion). But I have same files, same tables where I want to put data into. The issue only persists once the package is run by SQL Server Agent. Not manually from Visual Studio.

Comment: Khairul Alam what option?

Comment: You may check this option, Go to Properties of ssis project -> Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Debugging Options -> Run64BitRuntime. Set Run64BitRuntime = False. Save and Build the project then deploy again.

Comment: Khairul Alam, I've tried that one. It helped but with different error. The previous one referred to connection manager. And after I had changed Run64BitRuntime = False it was resolved. However now I am struggling with different issue which is described in this topic.

Comment: I *assume* this is happening in a Data Flow. if so, I suggest creating a Error Output in your Dataflow and storing the "bad" rows elsewhere. Then you can inspect them and see what row(s) it's failing on. I'm afraid all we have to go on is the error here, and we can't replicate it with just that information.

Comment: Yadam Voshack, You may cross check the running ssis version and  the Deployment Target Version.

Comment: SELECT @@version returns  Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU2-GDR) (KB4458621) - 13.0.5201.2 (X64)   Aug 18 2018 07:38:15   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor) 

while TargetServerVersion is SQL Server 2016

Comment: I suggest you narrow down to particular files and staging tables. The error would appear to be occurring on the table insert side. Once you have a failing file identified, remove rows until you find the row. That will give you a clue about the issue. You might think you are using the same file when in fact you aren't.... or you're not running the package you expect, or not inserting into the db you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally find an answer and will here share with you how to resolve it.

Even though the parameter Run64BitRuntime =false at Project Properties wchich I had deployed to SSIS catalog it looks like it was actually executed with 64bit mode as at Job Step properties at configuration tab you have option to run it with "32-bit runtime"

[Job Step Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6Dnc.png)